# Scrolling recyclerview in fragment causes view to be pushed up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image]

When I tried to scroll inside my recyclerview fragment, the entire view got pushed up.

Fragment Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

List Layout Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Toolbar Code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I've tried changing the fragment to wrap_content instead of match_parent and when I tried scrolling at the content area, the same problems occurs where the view will get pushed up

Comment: You have toolbar right? can you post your toolbar code?

Comment: Added the toolbar code

Comment: Try giving `match_parent` to the first `RelativeLayout` height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your toolbar scrollflags need to be changed like below,

```
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

instead of exitUntilCollapsed you can try some other properties also

1)enterAlways
2)enterAlwaysCollapsed

and your recyclerview parent RelativeLayout should have following properties.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. How could I do so when I scroll, the app bar hides but not the Tablayout

Comment: can't get you. please elaborate your question. and accept and upvote if the solution helps.

Comment: I would like the AppBar which now displays "Quido" to be hidden when scrolling, leaving only the TabBar visible

Comment: so, when you scroll Quido should be hide. isn't?

Comment: Its not hiding currently

Comment: you want to hide or not?

Comment: Yep. I want it to hide

Comment: there are some properties you can use with. i updated my answer. choose whichever is best to you.